# What does following a function with (jQuery, window, document); mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following plugin:

```
;(function($, window, document)
{
...
...

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I can understand what the ; is for and also realize that $ is the jQuery but can someone explain why is the function followed by (jQuery, window, document);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called a 'self ivoking' or 'immediately invoked' function. It means that the function is run as soon as it is created using the parameters in the final set of brackets.

[Further information](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/)

Comment: what does that ; mean in ;(function ?

Comment: @AshokRaj That is likely a way to assure that any code that hasn't been properly closed, prior to the function, gets closed so that it doesn't interfere with this code.

Comment: nice thank you :) wouldn't this result in recursion ??

Comment: @AshokRaj In what way do you think it would cause recursion?

Comment: i am sorry if wrong, but when the function itself is called at it's end, wouldn't that keep happening?

Comment: @AshokRaj no, it only occurs after the function is created.

Comment: oh.awesome..there are a lot usability i didn't know..

Answer (score 4):

This is called **Immediately-Invoked Function Expression** or **Self-executing anonymous function**. It enables the developer to hide his private declarations.

```
;(                                 // <---------------+
                                   //                 | encapsulate the function
  function($, window, document) {  // <--+ declare    | and call it passing three
                                   //    | anonymous  | arguments.
  }                                // <--+ function   |
                                   //                 |
)(jQuery, window, document);       // <---------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking, but what they do is that they pass the `jQuery` object, the `window` object and the `document` object to the function.

Most likely they do this for performance reasons. This makes it possible for a minimizer to shorten all the references to `window` and `document` to something like `w` and `d`, since it is local variables. In a large library, that could save a few bytes.

Additionally I believe *(have no reference atm)* that it is slightly faster to access a local variable, compared to a global variable (really a micro optimization though).

Answer (score 1):

It's an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

That means, the function is declared and executed right away. This this done in order to create a new scope.

Answer (score 1):

It's an anonymous function that's immediately invoked (the so called IIFE).

The passing of `jQuery` aliases it to `$`, and `window` and `document` so they can be sure the reference is to the correct version in the outside environment.