# Why do we use the dollar window and document method for binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do we use like this?

```
(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
.......
})(( jQuery, window, document );)
```

I think the $ is converted to jQuery, Ok! But why window, document?

And also, can I use my own selector method something like this?

```
var mydiv = $('#mydiv');    
(function( $, window, document, mydiv, undefined ) {
    .......
    })(( jQuery, window, document, mydiv );)
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724090/what-does-following-a-function-with-jquery-window-document-mean

Answer (score 0):

To make a locally scoped reference to window and document. This provides performance benefit.